# Use URI on expo Document-picker to get the file itself

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I got suck while trying to upload a file from react-native (android using expo) to a back-end server.
I got from `DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync()` this response

```
    {
      "name": "QuitusInscription_30769_59.pdf",
      "size": 41438,
      "type": "success",
      "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fcsdl_frontend-46ddf63e-90ab-44b3-a4c7-6ad7aad5cccc/DocumentPicker/a40a6599-4900-439a-9e9b-57fa555a80c9.pdf",
    }
```

My problem is now how to use the uri in order to get the file itself ? so that I could send it to the back-end server

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried ExpoFileSystem.readAsStringAsync?

For example, already having the uri you talked about:

```
import * as ExpoFileSystem from 'expo-file-system'
...
const fileContent = await ExpoFileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri);
```

And maybe you want to convert it from JSON to another format:

```
const content = JSON.parse(fileContent);
```